# How to convert mkv video to hls using compiled ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

With the following commands converting the mkv video into HLS master playlist based video streams is not working correctly.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv \
  -y -vsync 0 -c:v h264_cuvid -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a copy \
  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vf fade,hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=854:358 -b:v:0 1M -b:a:0 128k \
  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vf fade,hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=1280:536 -b:v:1 3M -b:a:1 192k \
  -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:480p v:1,a:1,name:720p" \
  -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 3 -hls_flags independent_segments -f hls -hls_playlist_type event -master_pl_name "master-pl.m3u8" output-%v.m3u8
```

And it is generating the output as follows which is wrong.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1240800,RESOLUTION=1280x536,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,ac-3"
output-480p.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3511200,RESOLUTION=1280x536,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,ac-3"
output-720p.m3u8
```

### Question

How to generate master playlist with ffmpeg (which was compiled to work with nvidia GPU)

### GPU compile configurations

```
--enable-nonfree --disable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-cuda --enable-nvenc --enable-cuvid --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-openssl --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

I have copied the multiple resolution based video generating based on following commands which works well, but it works with CPU I would like to convert it into GPU.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv \
-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 \
-c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a aac -ar 48000 \
-filter:v:0 scale=w=480:h=360  -maxrate:v:0 600k -b:a:0 64k  \
-filter:v:1 scale=w=640:h=480  -maxrate:v:1 900k -b:a:1 128k  \
-filter:v:2 scale=w=1280:h=720 -maxrate:v:2 900k -b:a:2 128k  \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:360p v:1,a:1,name:480p v:2,a:2,name:720p" \
-preset slow -hls_list_size 0 -threads 0 -f hls -hls_playlist_type event -hls_time 3 \
-hls_flags independent_segments -master_pl_name "name-pl.m3u8" \
"name-%v.m3u8"
```

Comment: Better to generate the master playlist in a hard coded way. With couple lines of code it can be handled

Comment: I will provide the answer below, quite later

Comment: *"is not working correctly"* How should it work, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: It is generating the resolutions wrong for some reason